# How to use php with sql query in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
var phpCode = '<?php 
        $sql = "SELECT Name,Surname,id_room FROM timatable.professors WHERE p.id_professor = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['hiddenProfId'])."'";
        $resutl = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        if ($result == 1 ) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $professorName = $row['Name'];
            $professorSurname = $row['Surname']; 
        } else echo "Error";
    ?>';
alert(phpCode);
```

this is my code. how to make it work ????

Comment: This is not possible, You can add the code, but it ll not execute since, php is serverside language.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to take the name and surname from DB and put  them in variables, professorName and professorSurname. the query is executing right but the variables are empty

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

First initialize, variables to null.

```
$professorName = "";
$professorSurname = "";
```

This is because, if php code enters else part, you will not get any error in javascript part.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT Name,Surname,id_room FROM timatable.professors WHERE p.id_professor = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['hiddenProfId'])."'";
    $resutl = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if ($result == 1 ) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $professorName = $row['Name'];
        $professorSurname = $row['Surname']; 
    } else echo "Error";
?>

<script>
    var professorName = "<?php echo $professorName ?>";
    var professorSurname = "<?php echo $professorSurname ?>";

    alert(professorName);
    alert(professorSurname);
</script>
```

Comment: In javascript its not possible. If you want, you can use ajax for this. And also in answer, you are able to get values in javascript. What is the problem there??

Comment: cause when I click a span I want a Javascript function to be executed

Comment: then its better to use ajax. Want me to edit my answer for that
??

Comment: no, thank you I just wanted to know if it possible with javascript

Comment: No, u shud use ajax only.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. So it is processed on a server. Therefore you cannot have a PHP code in javascript.

If you want to have javascript managed some editing in database, you can use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to do it without reloading the page.